# Serialized form is only sent to controller when it is the only parameter in the ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Ajax call.  I have 2 parameters.  One is a serialized form, and the other is a string.  When I only pass the form back, all values are present in the controller object.  However, when I pass both the serialized form and the string, the string is populated while the form object is null...

Not sure why this is so.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Jquery**

```
   function SubmitQuoteForm() {
       var selectedServices = MapServiceForm();
       var addressForm = $("#ShipmentForm").serialize();

       $.ajax({
        data: { addressModel: addressForm, serviceListing: selectedServices },
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/PrepareRateRequest",
        success: function (response) {
            //omitted for brevity
        }
    });

    function MapServiceForm() {
        var selectedServices = $("#ShipmentForm  input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function () {
           return this.id;
        }).get().join('|');

        return selectedServices;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult PrepareRateRequest(Models.ShipmentModel addressModel, string serviceListing)
    {
        //omitted for brevity

        return Json("");
    }
```